# What happens when an iPhone/iPad keyboard is shown/closed in Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

I'm trying to understand what happens after the "Done" button is clicked on the iPhone/iPad keyboard when viewing a webpage in Safari, specifically what events are fired.

From what I can gather so far, the text box that was selected loses it's focus.

Is this all that happens, or does the whole window lose it's focus?

I'm also interested to know if the showing of the keyboard causes any resize events to be fired?

Comment: Think if you see **Done** and not **Next**, pressing it would be same as pressing **Enter** and you should get 13 on keyup.

Comment: I don't think "Done" triggers that, but instead the "return" button (located where "Next" would have been). I have a jQuery autocomplete that loses it's focus when I press "Done", thus hiding the dropdown `<ul>` element. I'm trying to figure out a way of either intercepting the event that is triggered - or if it is just a simple blur event, catch it inside the jQuery autocomplete plugin.

Comment: There are too many android devices, 'Done' you are talking about is sometimes arrow down, which closes the keyboard. Think you are right and it will trigger 'blur', but I am more sure it will trigger **change**, which you need.